# MXNet print intermediate symbol values

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, mxnet

How do i find the actual numerical values held in an MXNet symbol.

Suppose I have,

```
x = mx.sym.Variable('x')
y = mx.sym.Variable('y')
z = x + y,
```

if x = [100,200] and y=[300,400],
I want to print:

`z = [400,600]`,

sort of like tensorflow's eval() method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking around a bit, I found you can do this by:

```
x = mx.sym.Variable('x')
y = mx.sym.Variable('y')
z = x + y
executor = z.bind(mx.cpu(), {'x': mx.nd.array([100,200]), 'y':mx.nd.array([300,400])})
output = executor.forward()
```

will give you the 'output':

```
[<NDArray 2 @cpu(0)>]
```

To print the actual numerical output:

```
print output[0].asnumpy()
array([ 400.,  600.], dtype=float32)
```